# Select cell value not the whole records

Tags: microsoft-access

When I'm trying to select all of the value for specific cell using Ctrl+A it selects all of the records,So how can I just select the value ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Does the regular copy command not copy the entire value? Do you have some sample data where this doesn't work?

Comment: Could someone please tell me why am I getting down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the cursor inside the field, press <kbd>Home</kbd> to move the cursor to the start of the data (if it isn't already), then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to select the entire content.

For fields containing integer data or text data with no delimiters (spaces/periods/slashes etc.), you can simply double-click within the field to select the entire content.